# NERDTree toggling and keyboard mapping

Tags: vim, nerdtree

I have this line in my .vimrc:

```
nmap <silent> <Leader>p :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

So what is the hotkey for toggling NERDTree?

How do I remap it to CTRL-D?

what is the difference between `nmap`, `map`, `nnoremap`, `inoremap`, etc?

Comment: the correct line should be nmap <silent> <leader>p :NERDTreeToggle<CR>

Answer (score 37, accepted):

to remap in normal mode use

```
nmap <silent> <C-D> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
```

`nmap` means map in normal mode
`imap` means map in insert mode

the `nore` part in `nnoremap` and its friends prevent expanding the mapping recursively.  For example, i use  to also hide search string so, in my vimrc I have

```
nnoremap <silent> <C-L> :noh<CR><C-L>
```

Without the `nore`, the above mapping will loop.

Comment: i tried both nmap <silent> <C-D> :NERDTreeToggle<CR> and nmap <silent> <c-d> :NERDTreeToggle<CR> but when i press CTRL-D it seems to scroll down about 33 lines...

Comment: You need to do the nnoremap because <c-d> is scroll down by default.

Comment: i changed it to nnoremap <silent> <C-D> :NERDTreeToggle<CR> but it still seems to scroll down when i press ctrl-D?

Comment: :map <c-d> :echo "hello"<CR> does it print hello on <C-d>?

Comment: i found that it does work if i put the entry in /etc/vim/vimrc.  it does not work if i put it in ~/.vim/vimrc...

Comment: I *thought* you did all the commands in vim ex-commandline! :)

Comment: strange, why is the ~/.vim/vimrc file not being used?

Comment: ~/.vimrc is the proper file name.

Answer (score -4):

@fcuk122 - try this nmap   :NERDTreeToggle
I think CTRL + D is already used in system try CRTL + T or any other convenient key and which not used by terminal or VIM.
may work for you.